# How to define events within a class in ECMA 6 using jquery selectors?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jquery-events

I've defined a class with the new standard ECMA6 and I want to put all the click events and other stuff within the class. How can I do that? I've search across several articles and none of them mention how to do this......I tried to define the events on the constructor like this but didn't work at all:

```
   class Grid{

        constructor(gridOptions) {
         this.grid_header='';
         this.grid_body='';
         this.grid='';   
         this.options=gridOptions;
         this.cacheDom();
         this.bindEvents();
         this.buildGrid();

       $( ".page" ).on( "click", function() {
               alert("hola");
             });


        }

        cacheDom() {
           this.$greeder = $(this.options.selector);
        } 

        bindEvents() {

        }

        buildGrid(page_number=1){


        }


    }
```

EDIT: I want that everytime that event gets triggered, to execute a method from my class

Comment: Your code works. It makes no sense to re-add the same event listeners each time you instantiate the constructor, but it will work.

Comment: "*I want to put all the click events and other stuff within the class*" - what is the problem with doing that? And what exactly do you want to put there (show us your code without `class`es)? jQuery event handling didn't change with ES6, just do it as before.

Comment: where should I put them if I want to respect the new standard??.....And the event is not working for me by the way

Comment: Probably you should use event delegation. If you have a class and there are elements that are generated by the class then you should think about a different approach for selecting the class-related elements.

Comment: could you give me an example or an article to get started with that?......I want that everytime that event gets triggered, to execute a method from my class.....

Comment: Here is the APIs listed under the category of `events` in jQuery website: https://api.jquery.com/category/events/. If you have a specific problem provide a fiddle that reproduces it.

Comment: nono, I know about those events, I use them all the time, I just want to know how to execute a method from my particular object everytime an event gets fired keeping my events related to the class somehow.......

Comment: @Juan: So, how would you have done this in ES5? It's quite the same in ES6.

Comment: I don't come from ES5, I just come from plain jquery and javascript

Comment: Events are defined by the DOM in the same way. Switching from ES5 to ES6 does not affect how events work.

Comment: ES5 is used for referring to one of the previous versions of JavaScript. It's not a different language.

Comment: please, could you give me a straight answer?  I DON'T KNOW how to do that, that's why I'm here. I just wanna know the right place to put an event related to a class in order to execute a method of that class. It's not the same language at all, things have changed and it can get confusing. I just want to avoid the spaguetti code of throwing events outside a class....I know how to do it that way, but I feel is not the best approach......

Comment: @Juan: What do you mean by "throwing events outside a class"? Please post that code.

Answer (score 3):

ES6 doesn't change the way jQuery and DOM events and event handlers work.

What you have currently should 'work', i.e. it should add a click handler for all the elements that have `.page` class name and exist in the DOM at the time that specific code is executed. If the elements are generated dynamically after the event binding then your code won't work as the target elements do no exist in the DOM yet. You should use event delegation.

```
$('aStaticParentSelector').on('event', '.selector', handler);
```

See [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

And if you have a class and there are elements that are generated by the class then you should think about a different approach for selecting the class-related elements.

```
class Foo {
   constructor() {
      this.$el = jQuery('<div class="page">').appendTo('.somewhere');
      this.$el.on('click', this.clickHandler.bind(this));
   }

   clickHandler(event) {
    // `this` keyword refers to the instance
    // `this.$el` => a jQuery wrapped element
    // `event.currentTarget` => the DOM element that is wrapped by jQuery in `this.$el`
   }
}
```

The above code uses [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) for setting the `this` value of the handler.

Please note that ES6 classes are just syntactic sugar and doesn't fundamentally change the way JavaScript OOP system work.

Comment: I like your second approach, but it's not working

`constructor(gridOptions) {
     this.grid_header='';
     this.filterRow='';
     this.grid_body='';
     this.grid='';   
     this.options=gridOptions;
     this.cacheDom();
     this.bindEvents();
     this.buildGrid();
     this.$page=$(".page");

     this.$page.on('click', this.changePage.bind(this));
     
    }`

I generate the page numbers on the constructor inside buildGrid().....

then I define the handler inside the class but it doesn't work

 `//events

      changePage(e) {
     alert(e);
     }`

Comment: @Juan Please provide a minimal demo in jsfiddle.net. Long code in the comment section is hard to read.

Comment: "*one of the lastest versions of JavaScript*"??? There's only one latest version at a time. (And currently it's ES7)

Comment: @Bergi  I'll remove that part.

Comment: Good example, but I think the parentheses after the class name should be removed.